# How to create a new tab with all columns where values are present and their corresponding row names?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My current table consists of rows of different categories and columns that represent different accounts. It looks like the following

```
              account 1, account 2, ..., account n
category 1                   15             22
         2       5                           3
         3       0            3
         ...
         m       3           10             15
```

I want to create a new tab that has all of the non-zero and not missing values, their corresponding category names matched with each account as follows

```
           account 1                 account 2 ...            account n
category 2     5        category  1       15       category 1     22
         m     3        category  3        3       category 2      3
                        category 10       10       category m     15
```

I need 1 column of space in between each category/account set. How would I go about doing this in Excel 2010 or 2013 if that matters?

Comment: You may want to consider using PivotTable for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    Dim srcWB As Workbook
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
    Dim srcRng As Range, rng As Range

    Set srcWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set srcWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet1")    '->enter sheet name with data
    Set destWS = srcWB.Sheets("Sheet2")    '->enter sheet name for result

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    '->gives last row with data
    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    '->gives last column with data

    With srcWS
        For i = 2 To lastColumn    '->loop through all columns
            Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(lastRow, i))
            Set rng = Union(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, i))    '->this line is for header
            For Each cel In srcRng
                If Not IsEmpty(cel) And cel.Value > 0 Then    '->check condition for blanks and 0's
                    Set rng = Union(rng, Union(.Cells(cel.Row, 1), cel))
                End If
            Next cel
            rng.Copy Destination:=destWS.Cells(1, ((i - 1) * 2 - 1))    '->paste range to destination sheet
            Set rng = Nothing    '->set rng to nothing
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

See image for reference:

**Source Sheet**

[image]

**Destination Sheet**

[image]